# How to print a nested list in a HTML file using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

I am trying to write a HTML file using python, and I want to print in .html a nested list.

I have written this, but I don´t have any idea about how to doit good.

```
words = [['Hi'], ['From'], ['Python']]

with open('mypage.html', 'w') as myFile:
    myFile.write('<html>')
    myFile.write('<body>')
    myFile.write('<h1>---------------------------</h1>')

    for i in range(len(words)):
        myFile.write('<tr><td>'(words[i])'</td></tr>')


    myFile.write('</body>')
    myFile.write('</html>')
```

In .html I want to print the nested list in a table in this similar format:

```
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Hi</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>From</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Python</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: What happens when you run your code? What do you want it to do differently?

Comment: Do you want to be able to handle something like `words = [['Hi', 'From', 'Python'], ['Goodbye', 'Java']]`? If so, what should the output be?

Comment: you are very close, you just need to add `<table>` and `</table>`. And `myFile.write(print("\n".join(["<tr><td>{}</td></tr>".format(x[0]) for x in words])))`

Comment: @D.Seah A nested for loop might be preferrable if the OP wants to be able to handle something like my previous example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
words = [['Hi'], ['From'], ['Python']]

with open('mypage.html', 'w') as myFile:
    myFile.write('<html>')
    myFile.write('<body>')
    myFile.write('<h1>---------------------------</h1>')

    
    # 2-depth string data to 1-depth 
    words = [word_str for inner in words for word_str in inner] 
    
    # use fstring to build string
    <table>
    for word in words:
        myFile.write(f'<tr><td>{word}</td></tr>') 
    </table>


    myFile.write('</body>')
    myFile.write('</html>')
```

I tried to edit the accepted answer but I were not available but, you just have to add `<table> and </table>`

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
words = [['Hi'], ['From'], ['Python']]

with open('mypage.html', 'w') as myFile:
    myFile.write('<html>')
    myFile.write('<body>')
    myFile.write('<h1>---------------------------</h1>')

    
    # 2-depth string data to 1-depth 
    words = [word_str for inner in words for word_str in inner] 
    
    # use fstring to build string
    for word in words:
        myFile.write(f'<tr><td>{word}</td></tr>')  


    myFile.write('</body>')
    myFile.write('</html>')
```

Comment: Please describe how this solves the OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [tabulate](https://github.com/astanin/python-tabulate) for this

```py
words = [['Hi'], ['From'], ['Python']]
print(tabulate(words, tablefmt="html"))
```

output:

```html
<table>
<tbody>
<tr><td>Hi    </td></tr>
<tr><td>From  </td></tr>
<tr><td>Python</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```